# How to export data from multiple tables using django-import-export

Tags: python, django

I have two models

```
Class Cdr(models.Model):
    account_code = models.Integer()
    caller_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    call_duration = models.Integer()


Class Users(models.Model):
    id = models.Integer()
    firstname= models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

There is no foreign key to connect this two models. 
**account_code** sometimes is equal to  **id**

I want to use the **django-import-export** module to export data that looks like this:

**account_code** | **caller_id** | **call_duration** |**Firstname**(where account_code=users.id)|

How do I go about it?